# How to specify column names while reading an Excel file using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I read an Excel Sheet into a pandas DataFrame this way:

```
import pandas as pd

xl = pd.ExcelFile("Path + filename")
df = xl.parse("Sheet1")
```

the first cell's value of each column is selected as the column name for the dataFrame, I want to specify my own column names, How do I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

call `.parse` with `header=None` keyword argument.

```
df = xl.parse("Sheet1", header=None)
```

Answer (score 19):

This thread is 5 years old and outdated now, but still shows up on the top of the list from a generic search. So I am adding this note. Pandas now (v0.22) has a keyword to specify column names at parsing Excel files. Use:

```
import pandas as pd
xl = pd.ExcelFile("Path + filename")
df = xl.parse("Sheet 1", header=None, names=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

If header=None is not set, pd seems to consider the first row as header and delete it during parsing. If there is indeed a header, but you dont want to use it, you have two choices, either (1) use "names" kwarg only; or (2) use "names" with header=None and skiprows=1. I personally prefer the second option, since it clearly makes note that the input file is not in the format I want, and that I am doing something to go around it.

Comment: Thanks, also to other answerers, for adding the additional notes on skipping the header row, which are not part of the question of OP, but essential for beginners on reading excel in python like us who got here at this question

Answer (score 17):

As Ram said, this post comes on the top and may be useful to some.... 
In pandas 0.24.2 (may be earlier as well), read_excel itself has the capability of ignoring the source headers and giving your own col names and few other good controls:

```
DID = pd.read_excel(file1, sheet_name=0, header=None, usecols=[0, 1, 6], names=['A', 'ID', 'B'], dtype={2:str}, skiprows=10)

# for example....
# usecols => read only specific col indexes
# dtype => specifying the data types
# skiprows => skip number of rows from the top.
```

Answer (score 14):

I think setting them afterwards is the only way in this case, so if you have for example four columns in your DataFrame:

```
df.columns = ['W','X','Y','Z']
```

If you know in advance what the headers in the Excelfile are its probably better to rename them, this would rename W into A, etc:

```
df.rename(columns={'W':'A', 'X':'B', etc})
```

Comment: my problem is that the first row of the Excel file contains valid data and not the column names. so using "df.columns = ['W','X','Y','Z']" I would lose data ... so I need to append the col names on top of existing data then change the col names ....

Answer (score 7):

In case the excel sheet only contains the data without headers:

```
df=pd.read_excel("the excel file",header=None,names=["A","B","C"])
```

In case the excel sheet already contains header names, then use `skiprows` to skip the line:

```
df=pd.read_excel("the excel file",header=None,names=["A","B","C"],skiprows=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you don't know the number of columns in excel beforehand and to use the same column names that excel uses: A, B etc you can use this option. Inspired from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19169180/1019156)

```
import string
df = pd.read_excel(wb_path, header=None)
def get_excel_col_name(col: int):
    result = []
    while col:
        col, rem = divmod(col-1, 26)
        result[:0] = string.ascii_uppercase[rem]
    return ''.join(result)
df.columns = [get_excel_col_name(x) for x in range(1, len(df.columns)+1)]
```