# Naming Columns of a dataset in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which consists of 1000 columns but is not labeled. I want to label them such as {A,B,C.....}. How can I do this in python ? Since the dataset is too large to name it manually.

Comment: Here are some nice generators: [Get Excel-Style Column Names from Column Number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153462/get-excel-style-column-names-from-column-number)

Comment: without any data defined columns you will just get numerically assigned columns from `0...N` when you create the df, the point being dfs always have an index and columns

Comment: So what should be done here ? Should I try to add a header to the df ? Which would act as column labels.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string conversions of their ASCII equivalent numbers to assign as the new column names. Now, two methods could be suggested to get those names and do the assignment.

Using `chr` on an array of ASCII equivalent numbers in a loop -

```
df.columns=[chr(item) for item in 65+np.arange(df.shape[1])]
```

Using method `view('U2')` on that array in a vectorized manner -

```
df.columns = (65+np.arange(df.shape[1])).view('U2')
```

I think we would have unwanted ascii equivalents once we run of the 26 alphabets. So, maybe not the solution we want when dealing with 1000 columns, as we need to define what's the expected output for such a case. I would leave the answer as it is for people who are dealing with limited number of columns in their dataframes.

Sample run -

```
In [159]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,9,(4,15)))

In [160]: df
Out[160]: 
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14
0   1   0   7   7   7   7   3   2   6   6   8   1   4   1   6
1   8   7   6   4   4   5   5   8   2   8   7   2   1   0   6
2   2   1   3   2   5   7   6   2   6   6   1   7   8   1   7
3   1   2   7   0   5   4   6   8   6   8   3   7   7   1   8

In [161]: df.columns = (65+np.arange(df.shape[1])).view('U2')

In [162]: df
Out[162]: 
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O
0  1  0  7  7  7  7  3  2  6  6  8  1  4  1  6
1  8  7  6  4  4  5  5  8  2  8  7  2  1  0  6
2  2  1  3  2  5  7  6  2  6  6  1  7  8  1  7
3  1  2  7  0  5  4  6  8  6  8  3  7  7  1  8
```

Comment: Since few of the values in the columns are more than 256, it is showing index out of range.

Comment: @user3848891 Yeah, because we have 256 as the max of ASCII equivalents. So, what must be the column labels after `A..Z`?