# A sequential counter

Tags: python

For this project I'm working on, I'm writing a way to sequentially find every possible combination of four letters.  I thought about writing a loop that increases i and convert i to base four and replace the 0's, 1's, 2's and 3's.  I ran into a problem when 00 wouldn't come up.  I thought about converting i into base 5 and ignoring every time 0 would show up, and replace the 1's, 2's, 3's and 4's.  It does work for me, but the problem is that it's not very efficient.

Here's the best code I have for now:

```
import string
digs = string.digits + string.letters
def int2base(x, base):
    if x < 0: sign = -1
    elif x == 0: return digs[0]
    else: sign = 1
    x *= sign
    digits = []
    while x:
        digits.append(digs[x % base])
        x /= base
    if sign < 0:
        digits.append('-')
    digits.reverse()
    return ''.join(digits)
for i in range(0,1000):
    x=i
    x=int2base(x, 5)
    if str(x).count("0")==0:
        print(i)
```

Is there any way that I can fix it so that it prints what it prints, but I just need to plug i into a function?
Example input and output

```
0 -> a
1 -> b
2 -> c
3 -> d
4 -> aa
5 -> ab
6 -> ac
7 -> ad
8 -> ba
9 -> bb
10 -> bc
11 -> bd
12 -> ca
13 -> cb
14 -> cc
15 -> cd
16 -> da
17 -> db
18 -> dc
19 -> dd
20 -> aaa
21 -> aab
```

Comment: Can you provide sample input and output so that I can be sure of whether you're looking for combinations, permutations, or a product?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Sure, I edited my post and added some examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want spreadsheet column numbers: [Get Excel-Style Column Names from Column Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153462/get-excel-style-column-names-from-column-number)

The following is based on an answer on that question:

```
digits = 'abcd'

def column(n):
    result = []
    while n:
        n, rem = divmod(n-1, len(digits))
        result.append(digits[rem])
    return ''.join(reversed(result))
```

when used results in the requested output:

```
>>> for i in range(22):
...     print i, '->', column(i+1)
... 
0 -> a
1 -> b
2 -> c
3 -> d
4 -> aa
5 -> ab
6 -> ac
7 -> ad
8 -> ba
9 -> bb
10 -> bc
11 -> bd
12 -> ca
13 -> cb
14 -> cc
15 -> cd
16 -> da
17 -> db
18 -> dc
19 -> dd
20 -> aaa
21 -> aab
```

Answer (score -1):

Module itertools.

```
import itertools

for acombo in itertools.product('ABCD', repeat=4):
    print acombo
```

Comment: This doesn't match the desired sample output.