# Pandas read_excel keep A:Z column names

Tags: python, excel, pandas

When importing an excel file to pandas using read_excel, I would like to keep the column and row names of excel.
I.e., I would like my columns to be named 'A','B',...'Z','AA','AB' etc. and rows from 1 and on.

Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need custom [mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19153462/2901002) and apply it to `rename`:

```
np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5,5)))
print (df)
   0  1  2  3  4
0  8  8  3  7  7
1  0  4  2  5  2
2  2  2  1  0  8
3  4  0  9  6  2
4  4  1  5  3  4

def colToExcel(col): # col is 1 based
    excelCol = str()
    div = col 
    while div:
        (div, mod) = divmod(div-1, 26) # will return (x, 0 .. 25)
        excelCol = chr(mod + 65) + excelCol

    return excelCol

df = df.rename(index=lambda x: x+1, columns=lambda y: colToExcel(y+1) )
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E
1  8  8  3  7  7
2  0  4  2  5  2
3  2  2  1  0  8
4  4  0  9  6  2
5  4  1  5  3  4
```

---

**Alternative:**

```
def conv(num):
    convStr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" # Assign any base you'd like
    b = len(convStr)
    if num<b:
        return convStr[num]
    else:
        return conv(num//b-1) + convStr[num%b]

df = df.rename(index=lambda x: x+1, columns=lambda y: colToExcel(y) )
```

Comment: Nice, but the colToExcel function looks overcomplicated. Or maybe not +1

Comment: @AntonvBR - yes, maybe it should be better, I want reuse only existing function ;) thank you.

Comment: tbh, this does the trick and I'm not sure how it could be better. Just my first thoght.

Comment: @AntonvBR - Thank you.

Comment: I looked around and adapted a function that can be used for any base.

Comment: hi @jezrael , why cant we use `chunksize in pd.read_excel` but we can perform with csv files

Comment: @pyd - not sure if understanf, why do you think so?

Comment: @pyd - I check it and you are right. [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html). Hard question, maybe not easy implement it to pandas.

Answer (score 0):

What I did some time ago: I specified the column names with column types and the "header" argument as "None":

```
def converter(dict):
            converter = {}
            for key in dict:
                converter[key] = str
            return converter

columntype_table = {'A': datatype.str,
                        'B': datatype.str,
                        'C': datatype.str,
                        'D': datatype.str,
                        'E': datatype.str,
                        'F': datatype.str,
                        'G': datatype.str,
                        'H': datatype.str}

data = pandas.read_excel(fileX, encoding=X, sheetname=Y, converters=converterDic(columns_dict), header=None)
```