# Give repeated excel strings a,b,c.. values using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel document which I has repeating names:

```
[IN]
    Block 14
    Block 14
    Block 14
    Block 14
    Block 14
    Block 14

    Block 15
    Block 15
    Block 15
    Block 15
    Block 15
    Block 15
```

I would like to give this an a, b, c value throughout, for example:

```
[OUT]
Block_14_a
Block_14_b
Block_14_c
Block_14_d
Block_14_e
Block_14_f

Block_15_a
Block_15_b
Block_15_c
Block_15_d
Block_15_e
Block_15_f
```

Does anyone have any idea how best to do this over a data set of a few hundred blocks ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More common is add numbers, but if need letters use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with [mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24861979/2901002):

```
def excel_col(col):
    """Covert 1-relative column number to excel-style column label."""
    quot, rem = divmod(col-1,26)
    return excel_col(quot) + chr(rem+ord('a')) if col!=0 else ''


df['col'] = df['col'] + '_' + df.groupby('col').cumcount().add(1).map(excel_col)
print (df)

           col
0   Block 14_a
1   Block 14_b
2   Block 14_c
3   Block 14_d
4   Block 14_e
5   Block 14_f
6   Block 15_a
7   Block 15_b
8   Block 15_c
9   Block 15_d
10  Block 15_e
11  Block 15_f
```