# Creating multiple empty list seperated by comma

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, indexing

I'm trying to write some dataframe to a csv file. However, the columns F to N should me empty. This is the dataframe im using:

```
data = [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['o']]
dataFrame = pandas.DataFrame(data).transpose()
```

The letters are to clarify under which column the data should go. For example, `'c'` is going under the column C. However, with the current line `'o'` goes under the column F. Is there a way to tell this dataFrame that it should skip columns F to N and write `'o'` under column O?

I assumed that's possible to write `[], [], []` many times but this seems a bit unnecessary. Is there a smart way to make multiple empty lists seperated by comma? Like the example above?

Thanks for reading. If anything is unclear please let me know!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a Pandas dataframe, what you desire is not possible. The name Pandas is derived from "panel data". As such, it's built around NumPy arrays, one for each series or "column" of data. You can't have "placeholders" for series which should be skipped over when exporting to a CSV or Excel file.

You can explicitly set your index equal to your dataframe values and then use [`pd.DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with a list of letters. If you have more than 26 columns, see [Get Excel-Style Column Names from Column Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153462/get-excel-style-column-names-from-column-number).

```
import pandas as pd
from string import ascii_lowercase

data = [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['o']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.index = df[0]

df = df.reindex(list(ascii_lowercase)).T.fillna('')

print(df[list('abcdefg') + list('mnopqrs')])

0  a  b  c  d  e f g m n  o p q r s
0  a  b  c  d  e          o
```

Comment: Is it possible to create empy lists seperated by comma's with python though?

Comment: @abdullah94300, Yes, but there's no reason for you to create empty lists with no meaning in your input. This is a workaround which avoids custom / boilerplate code. As you mention yourself: `I assumed that's possible to write [], [], [] many times but this seems a bit unnecessary.`

Comment: Is your answer the workaround? I like your answer very much. Don't get me wrong

Comment: @abdullah94300, Yep that's what I mean, the workaround is my answer. You can add empty lists, I just think this is distracting and ultimately not helpful.

Comment: I hope it was clear that my data is different from the one I gave here as an example. I get the following error: ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis. This happens when using the reindex() method

Comment: `I hope it was clear that my data is different from the one I gave here as an example.` Nope, sorry, it would help if you asked a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with your actual input since this one has been answered (and may accrue more answers).