# How to find row and column coordinates from an excel sheet for non-empty data?

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula, pywin32

What i am trying is get the excel data content with some color formatting and take screenshot and save the image.

My Business logic will look like this

```
def capture_multiple_images():
    capture_image("REPORT_1_NONCOLOR_TEST.xlsx","RSP_TIME.jpeg",13,12)  #upto 13 rows, 12 columns
    capture_image("REPORT_2_NONCOLOR_TEST.xlsx","FID_REPORT.jpeg",6,10)  #upto 6 rows, 10 columns
    capture_image("REPORT_3_NONCOLOR_TEST.xlsx","ERCD_TREND.jpeg",5,7)  #upto 5 rows, 7 columns
```

Capture_image method is having the following code  -

```
def capture_image(EXCEL_FILE,IMAGE_NAME,row,column):
    excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(os.path.join(Path.cwd(),EXCEL_FILE))
    ws = workbook.Worksheets['Sheet1']
    ws.Columns.AutoFit()
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(1,1),ws.Cells(row,column)).CopyPicture(Format= win32.constants.xlBitmap)  
    img = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
    cwd = Path.cwd()
    imgFile = os.path.join(cwd,IMAGE_NAME)
    print(imgFile)
    img.save(imgFile)
```

If you noticed i am getting the row, column from the user . So i want the coordinates dynamically based on the non empty cells. I dont need to mention the row, column every time . Because the excel files data are dynamic so i need a method to get the total rows and total columns is having only data.

Attached is my sample data, If you see the data here i need the coordinate of 5 rows and 7 columns from a program so that i can pass those data to my "capture_image" method. Instead of passing manually like this

```
capture_image("REPORT_3_NONCOLOR_TEST.xlsx","ERCD_TREND.jpeg",5,7)
```

but expected is

```
def get_row(excel_file):
    ######
    program to get the total number of rows is having non empty data
    return row_number

def get_column(excel_file):
    ######
    program to get the total number of columns is having non empty data
    return column_number
```

Now the expected method calling will be like this -

```
capture_image("REPORT_3_NONCOLOR_TEST.xlsx","ERCD_TREND.jpeg",get_row(excel_file),get_column(excel_file))
```

[image]

Comment: See [Get Excel-Style Column Names from Column Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153462/get-excel-style-column-names-from-column-number).

Comment: @martineau - The link you provided will be useful if we know the column & row number . What i need is to get the column , row number .

Comment: Will the data be the only thing on the sheet? will the columns always have the same headers? (Or will any column have a consistent header: eg First column always "Service"?). If so you can use `Range.Find` to locate start of table; and a variety of methods to locate last row/column, including `Range.CurrentRegion` if the table is contiguous.

Comment: Get the row and column from what?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - Yes Data will be always there and First column will always be the "service" but not necessarily the other columns. And Range function is useful only if we knows the definite rows and columns. But what i want is to get the total rows and columns number which is having only data .

Comment: @martineau - Get the row and column from the excel sheet. I edited the question with the expected method.

Comment: There are several third-party Python modules available that support reading Excel files. Using one might be the easiest way to implement the `get_row()` and `get_column()` functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code solved my problem -

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook("REPORT_3_NONCOLOR_TEST.xlsx")

print(wb.worksheets[0].max_row)
print( (wb.worksheets[0].max_column))
```

Now i can call the method like this  -

```
capture_image("REPORT_3_NONCOLOR_TEST.xlsx","ERCD_TREND.jpeg",wb.worksheets[0].max_row,wb.worksheets[0].max_column)
```