# How to reate a dataframe based on excel sheet name and cell position?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have an excel table (sample.xlsx) which contains 3 sheets ('Sheet1','Sheet2','Sheet3').
Now I have read all the sheets and combine them into one dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd
data_df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel("sample.xlsx", header=None, index_col=None, sheet_name=None))
```

data_df looks like this:

```
              0      1      2
Sheet1 0   val1   val2   val3
       1  val11  val21  val31
Sheet2 0   val1   val2   val3
       1  val11  val21  val31
Sheet3 0   val1   val2   val3
       1  val11  val21  val31
```

Is there any way to create a new dataframe which has the same shape with data_df but each cell value is the cell position info?

I have tried to get multiple index:

```py
multi_index = data_df.index.levels[:]
```

and I get:

```py
[['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3'], [0, 1]]
```

But I don't know how to use these data to create a new dataframe like this:

```
             0            1            2
0  Sheet1 - A1  Sheet1 - B1  Sheet1 - C1
1  Sheet1 - A2  Sheet1 - B2  Sheet1 - C2
2  Sheet2 - A1  Sheet2 - B1  Sheet2 - C1
3  Sheet2 - A2  Sheet2 - B2  Sheet2 - C2
4  Sheet3 - A1  Sheet3 - B1  Sheet3 - C1
5  Sheet3 - A2  Sheet3 - B2  Sheet3 - C2
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the values in your `data_df` don't matter, you could build the cartesian product of index and columns and build a new dataframe of it.

```
mapping = dict(enumerate('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'))
```

mapping is needed to convert the column numbers 0,1,2,... to A,B,C,...
**UPDATE**
In case you have excel sheets with more than 26 columns, you would need to do some more calculations to get the Excel column names like `AA, AB,...AZ` and so on. In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153462/get-excel-style-column-names-from-column-number) there are several answers which cover that issue.

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

out = (
    pd.DataFrame(
        np.array([f"{x[0][0]} - {mapping[int(x[1])]}{x[0][1]+1}" 
                  for x in itertools.product(data_df.index, data_df.columns)])
        .reshape(len(data_df), -1)
    )
)

print(out)
```

```
             0            1            2
0  Sheet1 - A1  Sheet1 - B1  Sheet1 - C1
1  Sheet1 - A2  Sheet1 - B2  Sheet1 - C2
2  Sheet2 - A1  Sheet2 - B1  Sheet2 - C1
3  Sheet2 - A2  Sheet2 - B2  Sheet2 - C2
4  Sheet3 - A1  Sheet3 - B1  Sheet3 - C1
5  Sheet3 - A2  Sheet3 - B2  Sheet3 - C2
```

Comment: The idea is interesting. In terms of implementation - an error when the number of columns > 26 and in `len(df)` (apparently, you need `len(data_df)`?)

Comment: thanks, forgot to change the name there. That's true, good point, didn't think about that. Any idea how we could continue from there like it would be in excel (AA, AB, AC,...)?

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the “openpyxl” package. I think you can do something like “for sheet in sheets” then read each sheet to your data frame like that. Hope this guides you to the right place.

Comment: thanks for your advice, but I think there might be something wrong with my description. openpyxl could read the table and index cell value like sheet1['A1'], but actually I just want to create a dataframe which have the same shape with the data_df but each cell value is exactly its position info.